# Find siblings for the clicked element

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have the following list structure:

```
<ul>
    <a class="target">one</a>
    <a class="target">two</a>
    <a class="target">three</a>
</ul>
```

When i click an `<a>` element I add an "selected" class for the clicked element and a "unselected" class for the others a elements like this:

```
$(".target").click(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selectedClass"); //remove "selected" class from siblings
    $(this).addClass("selectedClass"); //add selected class to clicked element
}
```

Now comes my problem.If I change the list structure as follows(wrap the `<a>` into divs):

```
    <ul>
    <div><a class="target">one</a></div
    <div><a class="target">two</a></div
    <div><a class="target">three</a></div
    </ul>
```

I don't know how to find the siblings (the others `<a>` elements) for the one I clicked.

```
    $(".target").click(){
        // how to target the others two <a> elements to call removeClass on them?    
        $(this).addClass("selectedClass"); //add selected class to clicked element - still works
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The child of an `ul` has to be `li`.

Comment: The JavaScript is not invalid, but certainly wouldn't do what you think it's supposed to do :)

Comment: @Jack In what way it is valid.. and it would be helpful if you open up your mouth regarding that.. Thanks. And a link related to that also be helpful..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I'm not sure whether it's the language barrier, but that came across as very rude so I shall not entertain it with a response.

Comment: @Jack oh.. ok wait, "**it would be helpful if you tell some thing about that**.. " Sorry just typed that out in a hurry..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy The code is valid in the sense that it just triggers a click event `$('.target').click()` and what follows is just a code block that will add a class to `window` (which probably has no effect).

Comment: @Jack `{ code goes here }` Does it a piece of valid code.? I did not use things like this before..? is there a technical name for that way of coding..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy The technical name for that is nonsensical I guess.

Comment: @Jack Oh yeah.. I must have avoided opening your mouth.. Stinks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just confused up with the syntaxes in binding a click event,

```
$(".target").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selectedClass"); //remove "selected" class from siblings
    $(this).addClass("selectedClass"); //add selected class to clicked element
});
```

You supposed to write the click event's code inside an anonymous function. or simply write the code in a separate function and just pass the reference to it.

I just saw your html structure, its **invalid**. Anchor tag should not be the direct child of an unordered list.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UB99x/)

Modified HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="target">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="target">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="target">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Modified JS:

```
$(".target").click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent()
    parent.siblings().removeClass("selectedClass"); //remove "selected" class from siblings
    parent.addClass("selectedClass"); //add selected class to clicked element
});
```

Comment: About, the html, I forgot the put the <li> tags here. The Jquery part is awesome, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can design it in such a way whereby it's not necessary to know exactly where the other items are; for instance, by keeping the last selected element and changing only that and the one currently clicked:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $current = $();

    $(".target").click(function() {
        $current.removeClass('selectedClass');
        $current = $(this).addClass('selectedClass');
    });
});
```

Alternatively, just cache all the target elements in one go:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $targets = $('.target');

    $targets.on('click', function() {
        $targets.removeClass('selectedClass');
        $(this).addClass('selectedClass');
    });
});
```